# Include login methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I got an entity User and i want every method of every controller to have the access to the logged user without typing anything like :

```
model.addAttribute(userDao.getuser(principal.getUsername()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a simple `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` that will add the user instance to the model after a handler is invoked.

```
class UserAddingHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    // Autowire dependencies...

    private static final String ATTRIBUTE = "user";

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
                           HttpServletResponse response, 
                           Object handler, 
                           ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

        if (modelAndView != null && !modelAndView.getModelMap().hasAttribute(ATTRIBUTE) {
            modelAndView.addObject(ATTRIBUTE, userDao.getuser(principal.getUsername()));
        }
    }
}
```